# Change value of `minicolors()` on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have multiple boxes with different background-color, color, border, etc, I have set `minicolors()` to get and set values of boxes, I have a pre-select box and all `minicolors()` background working fine , but when I clicked another box to get colors, input values are update but minicolors() value remain the same as it set first time until I change all inputs values. i want to update background of `minicolors()`, how i can change the value of minicolors() ?

```
 $(function() {
      var mini = [ '.minicolor_msg_bg_clr', '.minicolor_msg_txt_clr','.minicolor_msg_bdr_clr', '.minicolor_tier_bg_clr', '.minicolor_tier_txt_clr','.minicolor_tier_bdr_clr','.minicolor_box_bg'];
      $(mini).minicolors({
          position: 'bottom right',
          theme: 'bootstrap',
      });
  });
```

i want to update background color of minicolors() in this `onclick`

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('boxex')){
      $('.select').removeClass('select');
      $(this).addClass('select');
      $('#show').html(($('.select').html()));     
   }
 });
```

Comment: Does the plugin have any update options methods? Not known what that plugin does or what relationship those classes have to what you are clicking